# Lenovo Legion Y520 with Ubuntu 17.10 – Nvidia driver and settings

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, ubuntu-gnome

I bought a new Lenovo Legion Y520 and wiped Windows 10 Home because I don't like and need it. The notebook comes with a Nvidia GTX 1050 and I was wondering what's the proper way to set up the graphics for occasional playing. With a fresh ubuntu setup, default drivers and settings I tried playing "Cities Skylines" with a lot of graphical issues (texture glitches, intolerable freezes and so on) so I assume my graphics aren't set up well. I tried a few things like simply updating Nvidia driver to 390 without any changes and started it over. Do you have any advices for me how to go on from a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 installation? Hope you guys could help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi there you can check out this video https://youtu.be/PeWTSprpq1M.

1. Update your Ubuntu with "Software Updater", even after fresh install!
2. Open Activities or just press Windows key on your keyboard, then type "Software & Updates" (an app that have box and globe icon)
3. Go the "Additional Driver" tab and wait for second, they will scanning your hardware
4. Click and choose Using NVIDIA binary driver ..... like this picture

[Click this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ9CM.png)

5. Then click "Apply Changes"
6. Restart your PC after changes applied
7. To verify your NVIDIA work or not, just search if there's a "NVIDIA X Server Setting" and if it there's just open it. If it opens correctly then congratulations!

But try to read the comment on the video. Some people experiencing error and broke their machine. But for me It's work, so be wise.

I use the same laptop as yours, Lenovo Legion Y520 i7 quad core, GTX 1050, Ubuntu 17.10, hope this help you.

Comment: @Fabby Sorry, I'm still newbie on this forum, hope I edited it correctly. Thx